# How to test second activity started in instrumentation test in MVP?

Tags: android, android-intent, mvp, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am new to MVP in android.

My question is related to Instrumentation test in android. I am calling `second_activity()` in `main_activity()` using intent. So how can I test whether `second_activity` is called or not in instrumentation test using espresso.

I have successfully tested in unit test using junit and mockito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Let me explain what I did.

First step: Place your intent into a method in main activity

```
public void gotoSecond() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

And then place this code in Instrumenation test class file.

```
private MainActivity mTestActivity;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);

public MainActivityTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mTestActivity = getActivity();
}

@Test
public void testSecond(){
   //calling activity method using getActivity()
    mTestActivity.gotoSecond();
}
```

hope this will help someone who needs.